# java gRPC bi-stream disconnect: client Cancelled unexpected

Tags: scala, grpc, grpc-java

I'm developing a runtime game server which heavily use java-gRPC bi-stream. The data flow like this:
`Client <--grpc bi-stream--> Gateway Server <---- grpc bi-stream -----> Game Server`.

The problem show by a simple scene example:

Gateway Server hold bi-stream like this (NOTICE: code is Scala language, compile to JVM class, just consider it like python if you from Java):

```
  // Gateway Server gRPC bi-stream API
  override def stateSyncStreamDemo(
    responseObserver: StreamObserver[StateSyncFrameDemo]
  ): StreamObserver[StateSyncStreamRequestDemo] = {
    // get context from gRPC interceptor
      val `Context-UserId-Key` =
    Context.key[String]("user-id")
      val `Context-RoomId-Key` =
    Context.key[String]("room-id")

  new StreamObserver[StateSyncStreamRequestDemo] {
      override def onNext(
        request: StateSyncStreamRequestDemo
      ): Unit = {
        // send to Game Server by gRPC bi-stream
        // 1. create bi-stream to Game Server if roomId not create before
        val streamConnection = getOrCreateRoomConnection(`Context-RoomId-Key`)
        val gameServerRequestStream = streamConnection.withCallCredentials(
          new StreamShardingClient.ClientMetadataCall(
            roomId // setting roomId to Metadata
          )
        ). sendWithBiStream(someResponseStreamDefined)
        // 2. send message forward to Game Server with userId and client cmd
        gameServerRequestStream.onNext(Message(request.cmd, userId))
      }
   ...
```

This forward pattern works well usually.
A problem occurred when I disconnection client grpc (I'm test with `grpcurl`), the stream of Gaetway Server <-> Game Server disconnected too. Error message like this:

```
CANCELLED: client cancelled
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: client cancelled
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:530) ~[grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$StreamingServerCallHandler$StreamingServerCallListener.onCancel(ServerCalls.java:291) [grpc-stub-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.PartialForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(PartialForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) [grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:23) [grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.ForwardingServerCallListener$SimpleForwardingServerCallListener.onCancel(ForwardingServerCallListener.java:40) [grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.Contexts$ContextualizedServerCallListener.onCancel(Contexts.java:96) [grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closedInternal(ServerCallImpl.java:378) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.closed(ServerCallImpl.java:365) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1Closed.runInContext(ServerImpl.java:923) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
```

I'm just expect only disconnect client <-> Gateway Server. Why affet Game Server connection? Thanks

==========UPDATE========
I'm find it's relative with Context management, after setting `Context.fork()` in interceptor, `Gateway Server` can send message to `Game Server` success but there are error when push stream message from `Game Server` to `Gateway Server`, error this:

```
StreamShardingClient.error occurred. CANCELLED: Failed to read message.
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: Failed to read message.
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:539) ~[grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:487) [grpc-stub-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener$3.run(DelayedClientCall.java:489) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.delayOrExecute(DelayedClientCall.java:453) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onClose(DelayedClientCall.java:486) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.closeObserver(ClientCallImpl.java:576) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.access$300(ClientCallImpl.java:70) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:757) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1StreamClosed.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:736) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ContextRunnable.run(ContextRunnable.java:37) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor.run(SerializingExecutor.java:133) [grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED: call already cancelled. Use ServerCallStreamObserver.setOnCancelHandler() to disable this exception
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:530) ~[grpc-api-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ServerCallStreamObserverImpl.onNext(ServerCalls.java:366) ~[grpc-stub-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at scalasharding.sharding.StreamShardingClient$ResponseObserver.$anonfun$onNext$1(StreamShardingClient.scala:124) ~[classes/:?]
    at scalasharding.sharding.StreamShardingClient$ResponseObserver.$anonfun$onNext$1$adapted(StreamShardingClient.scala:117) ~[classes/:?]
    at scala.collection.immutable.Set$Set2.foreach(Set.scala:201) ~[scala-library-2.13.7.jar:?]
    at scalasharding.sharding.StreamShardingClient$ResponseObserver.onNext(StreamShardingClient.scala:117) ~[classes/:?]
    at scalasharding.sharding.StreamShardingClient$ResponseObserver.onNext(StreamShardingClient.scala:71) [classes/:?]
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onMessage(ClientCalls.java:474) ~[grpc-stub-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.DelayedClientCall$DelayedListener.onMessage(DelayedClientCall.java:473) ~[grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInternal(ClientCallImpl.java:675) ~[grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$1MessagesAvailable.runInContext(ClientCallImpl.java:660) ~[grpc-core-1.52.1.jar:1.52.1]
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the [examples](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples) from the lib? You have a directory that has examples for [cancellation](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/tree/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/cancellation). One for the [client](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/cancellation/CancellationClient.java), another one for the [server](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/main/java/io/grpc/examples/cancellation/CancellationServer.java). In the [README.md](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/README.md) shows how to build and run them locally.

What I can understand from there, is that [StreamObserver](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/stub/src/main/java/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.java) is an `interface` with three non implemented methods. One is the [onNext](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/df85a45742b0a1f43cbb492be1ea064fe1540154/stub/src/main/java/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.java#L62) which is the one you are showing in the provided piece of code in your question. The other two are [onError](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/df85a45742b0a1f43cbb492be1ea064fe1540154/stub/src/main/java/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.java#L79) and [onCompleted](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/df85a45742b0a1f43cbb492be1ea064fe1540154/stub/src/main/java/io/grpc/stub/StreamObserver.java#L88).

If I'm not wrong, in each example (**Client** and **Server**) you can see that the `onError` is being overriden without too much logic, but looks like that is where the errors are being handled. Also you have other observers such as `ClientCallStreamObserver` and `ServerCallStreamObserver` that are being used in the example.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes. You are right. There are logic exception in server inner gRPC `onNext` method and I'm not catch.

Comment: I have solved the logic error and bi-stream works well! The only problem is I'm not add `Context.fork()` in interceptor at the beginning. It will cause gRPC disconnect in a cascade when multiple gRPC call's Context in the same thread.